# How to send email using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to send an email and I follow this tutorial

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

and this is how I proceed:

my emailer.rb

```
class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "r.karoui@gmail.com"
  def emprunt_mail(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Emprunt de livre')
   end
  end
```

my emrunt_mail.erb.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1>Bonjour, <%= current_user.f_name %></h1>
      <p>
       Vous venez d'emprunter un livre
      </p>
      <p>
        vous avez une durée d'une semaine pour le rendre !
      </p>
      <p>Bonne journée!</p>
     </body>
   </html>
```

in my books_controller.rb

```
def emprunter
 if (@book.state == false)
  if @book.update(state: 1)
    flash[:notice]='Vous aver un délai de 7 jours pour rendre le livre'
    Emailer.create_emprunt_mail(current_user)
    Emailer.deliver_emprunt_mail(current_user)
    redirect_to books_list_path
  else
    redirect_to admin_manage_path
  end
 else
   flash[:notice]='Ce livre est déja pris'
   redirect_to books_list_path
   end

 end
```

I add this confguration to mt environment/developpment.rb

```
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors =true
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options ={ :host => 'localhost:3000'}
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings= {
  adress: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: "587",
  domain: "gmail.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_startlls_auto: true,
  user_name: 'USERNAME',
  password: '*********'

  }
```

and I did not add any route
the strage bihavior is that in emprunter method it pass to the else of the first if and it should enter to the block if .

**update**

in my server i have now this

> " Rendered emailer/emprunt_mail.html.erb (0.0ms)

```
Emailer#emprunt_mail: processed outbound mail in 4.1ms

Sent mail to rawia.seller@gmail.com (3.3ms)
 Date: Tue, 11 Nov 2014 11:40:31 +0100
 From: karoui.rawia@gmail.com
 To: rawia.seller@gmail.com
  Message-ID: <5461e79fd9674_4b33ffe529d82a44d0@imac-de-imac.home.mail>
 Subject: Emprunt de livre
 Mime-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta content=3D'text/html; charset=3DUTF-8' http-equiv=3D'Content-Type=
  ' />
    </head>
   <body>
   <h1>Bonjour, </h1>
    <p>
      Vous venez d'emprunter un livre
    </p>
    <p>
      vous avez une dur=C3=A9e d'une semaine pour le rendre !
    </p>
     <p>Bonne journ=C3=A9e!</p>
     </body>
     </html>=

     Redirected to http://localhost:3000/books/show
      Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

but when i check for mail i did not find any new one!! Could please tell me where is the problem

this is the new configuration in environment/developpment.rb:

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  # ActionMailer Config
  # Setup for production - deliveries, no errors raised
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings= {
  adress: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "gmail.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: 'username',
  password: '*****'
```

}

Comment: I fixed that problem by using this two line "config.action_mailer.delivery_method       = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true "

Comment: But now I have this error "454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem"

Comment: Please edit your original question with any new details - they may be missed if they are simply added as comments.

Comment: it looks like you have address spelled wrong